# will dataproc cluster initialization affect the dataproc jobs

Tags: google-cloud-dataproc

I have few dataproc clusters with the same properties enabled. But on cluster "A" I am able to get the jobs from the API "*dataproc.googleapis.com*" But on cluster "B" I am not able to get the dataproc jobs. Only difference I see between the clusters is the initialization. We have to get the dataproc jobs and populate into a table. Any thoughts on other reasons for this. Thanks.

**Cluster A Initialization actions:**

Pip install,
Configure Pip,
Purge yarn locals,
cloud sql proxy,
Conda-install-python,
copy-vennv-cron-multiversion

**Cluster B Initialization actions:**

Pip install,
Configure Pip,
Purge yarn locals,
cloud sql proxy

Comment: No, that shouldn't make a difference.

Comment: Thanks. But I am not able to get the jobs for Cluster B also from google cloud shell.  Please let me know if you have any thoughts on that.

Comment: Could you share the command and output?

Comment: gcloud dataproc jobs list --filter='placement.clusterName = B AND labels.execution_date=2022-10-09'
output - Listed 0 items.

Comment: What about you use `gcloud dataproc jobs list --cluster=<name>`?

Comment: That works in the gcloud shell. But when I try in the code as         `data = client.list_jobs(project_id=project_id, region='us-central1',
                               filter=f"clusterName={cluster_name} AND labels.execution_date={start_date}") `that doesn't work. So I tried      `data = client.list_jobs(project_id=project_id, region='us-central1',cluster=cluster_name,
                                filter=f"labels.execution_date={start_date}")`.  That is also not working. I am getting the error list_jobs() got an unexpected keyword argument 'cluster' .

Comment: You can add `--log-http` in the gcloud command to see what it is sending.

Comment: I get the Get request empty with the comment - Body redacted: Contains oauth token. Set log_http_redact_token property to false to print the body of this request. And then I get a list of hive jobs.

Comment: I found that certain jobs did not have labels associated. So the filter clause did not retrieve those jobs. I also the execution date in multiple formats like "2022-10-18","20221018". Is it possible to filter both of those formats in one filter. I tried this `client.list_jobs(project_id=project_id, region='us-central1',
                                filter=f"clusterName={cluster_name} AND (labels.execution_date = {start_date_int} OR labels.execution_date = {start_date}) ")` where start_date_int = 20221028 and start_date ="2022-10-18". I am getting  Unsupported filter format error.